# Join two dataframes if there's a match between their columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have this two DFs.
This is DF1['nice_in_here']:

```
                         nice_in_here
0                                 NaN
1                            Krystyna
2                               Piotr  
3                            Domicela
4                                Jaro
```

This is DF2[['nice_in_there','current_club']]:

```
    nice_in_there               current_club
0   Krystyna                    Klub-Duzych-Pup
1   Elżbieta                    NaN
2   Domicela                    NaN
3   Piotr                       Klub-Duzych-Pup
```

So what i want is:

to check if DF2["nice_in_there"] is in DF1["nice_in_here"] and if so, I want to join corresponding DF2["current_club"] to DF1["nice-in_here"].

The result I want to have is (after typing DF1[['nice_in_here','current_club']]):

```
                         nice_in_here        current_club
0                                 NaN                 NaN
1                            Krystyna     Klub-Duzych-Pup
2                               Piotr     Klub-Duzych-Pup
3                            Domicela                 NaN
4                                Jaro                 NaN
```

Note that I don't want to drop NaN as missing value is important for me.

Please help, this is driving me mad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
pd.merge(DF1, DF2, how="left", left_on="nice_in_here", right_on="nice_in_there")
```